# ansible undefined variable for a play while creating an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am getting the `undefined variable` error while creating EC2 instance in AWS Cloud with Ansible playbook.

My Ansible version is `2.9`.

My Playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Running AWS EC2 Play ...
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - include_vars: aws_vars.yml

    - name: Setting up the Security Group for new instance
      ec2_group:
          name: "{{ aws_hostname }}-nsg"
          description: Allowing Traffic on port 22 and 80
          region: "{{ aws_region }}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{ SecretKey }}"
          aws_access_key: "{{ AccessKey }}"

          rules:
           - proto: tcp
             from_port: 22
             to_port: 22
             cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

           - proto: tcp
             from_port: 80
             to_port: 80
             cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

          rules_egress:
           - proto: all
             cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
          vpc_id: "{{ aws_vpc_id }}"

    - name: Spinning up new aws ec2 instance
      ec2:
          aws_access_key: "{{ AccessKey }}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{ SecretKey }}"
          image: "{{ aws_image_id }}"
          instance_type: "{{ aws_instance_type }}"
          instance_tags: { "Name":"{{ aws_hostname }}", "Vendor": "Amazon" }
          key_name: "{{ aws_instance_key }}"
          assign_public_ip: no
          count: 1
          wait: yes
          wait_timeout: 500
          region: "{{ aws_region }}"
          volumes:
            - device_name: "{{ aws_device_name }}"
              device_type: "{{ aws_device_type }}"
              volume_size: "{{ aws_volume_size }}"
              delete_on_termination: true
          vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_subnet_id }}"
          group: "{{ aws_hostname }}-nsg"
          user_data: hostnamectl set-hostname "{{ aws_hostname }}"
      register: ec2_result

    - debug:
        var: ec2_result

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for:
        host: '{{ private_ip }}'
        port: 22
        delay: 60
        timeout: 320
        state: started
      loop: '{{ ec2_result.instances }}'

    - name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: '{{ private_ip }}'
        groups: ec2_hosts
      loop: '{{ ec2_result.instances }}'
```

The error

```
TASK [Wait for SSH to come up] ******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/user1/create_awsVM.yml:61
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'private_ip' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user1/create_awsVM.yml': line 61, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Wait for SSH to come up\n      ^ here\n"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What I also tried:

```yaml
- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  wait_for:
    host: '{{ item.private_ip }}'
    port: 22
    delay: 60
    timeout: 320
    state: started
  loop: '{{ ec2_result.instances }}'
```

I used `item` as `item.private_ip` as thought it might work with `loop` but no luck.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: And what is the error yield by Ansible to you when using `'{{ item.private_ip }}'`? Because this is the correct syntax to use.

Comment: Mind that you are using `'{{ private_ip }}'` in two tasks, so you might want to update it in **both** your `wait_for` **and** `add_host` tasks

Comment: what is the result of your debug task?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε i have changed that into both the location and its works now, thank you.